# Turning Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1) into seq("a","a","b") using map

Tags: scala, loops, iterator, higher-order-functions, simplification

I am trying to turn a Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1) into seq("a","a","b") through the map function, Currently I am trying to run the code below giving me the desired result.

Is there a smarter way to do this? Possibly a better way through the map function?

```
    var multiset : Seq[T] = Seq[T]()
    var variables : Seq[T] = data.map(x => x._1).toSeq
    var variableCounts : Seq[Int] = data.map(x => x._2).toSeq
    for(x <- 0 until variables.length){
        for(y <- 0 until variableCounts(x))
            multiset = multiset :+ variables(x)
    }
```

Comment: Is your data actually in shape `("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1)` or is it `Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1)` ? because the former is not a `Map`

Comment: Not sure what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like this:
Use fill method of `GenTraversableFactory` `def fill[A](n: Int)(elem: => A): CC[A]` from the definition of fill we can see that it takes an integer and an element. Integer tell how many times we need to fill the given element.

```
object Demo extends App {

  val x = Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1)

  val p: Seq[String] = x.flatMap { tuple =>
    List.fill(tuple._2)(tuple._1)
  }.toSeq

  print(p)
//output: List(a, a, b)
}
```

I Hope it helps!!!

If you want to avoid tuple._1 and tuple._1 you can use the following approach.

```
object Demo extends App {

  val x = Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1)

  val p: Seq[String] = x.flatMap { case (key, value) =>
    List.fill(value)(key)
  }.toSeq

  print(p)
//output: List(a, a, b)
}
```

Comment: You could use `x.flatMap { case (key, value) => ...}` to avoid using `._1`/`._2` too.

Comment: it's just a same thing, thanks for suggestion updating my answer with one more approach. @Marth

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what the shape of your data is. That part is a little bit unclear from the question.

```
Map('a' -> 3, 'b' -> 1)
```

Is indeed a Map. Whereas

```
('a' -> 3, 'b' -> 1)
```

desugars in a Tuple

```
(('a', 3), ('b', 1))
```

If it is the former case you can fold like this

```
val m : Map[String, Int] =  Map("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1) 
val res = m.foldLeft(List[String]())((a, b) => a ++ List.fill(b._2)(b._1))
```

here `res` will be `List('a', 'a', 'b')`

What is going on here is that we start with an empty accumulator, iterate through the key-value pairs of the Map, create a list that repeats the given key, value times and concat it to the accumulator

The latter is unfortunately a little harder without using something like `Shapeless` since in Scala 2 the type information will get lost when converting from a Tuple. You need to do some type juggling with the annotations

```
val ml = ("a" -> 2, "b" -> 1).productIterator
ml.foldLeft(List[String]())((a, b) => b match{ 
   case (k: String, v : Int) => a ++ List.fill(v)(k)
})
```